# Push Id, typography and active and convert recursively nested JSON to Flat JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I am trying to push the Id, typography and active and converting the nested one to flat JSON to use ReactDND npm library

I have JSON like this

```
[
  {
    "menuHead": [
      {
        "name": "MenuHead 01",
        "description": "sample Head 01",
        "icon": "sample01.png",
        "products": []
      },
      {
        "name": "MenuHead 02",
        "description": "sample Head 01",
        "icon": "sample01.png",
        "products01": [
          {
            "name": "product 01",
            "description": "sample product ONE",
            "icon": "product01.png",
            "section": [
              {
                "name": "section01",
                "description": "ActiveLayer",
                "icon": "img.png",
                "min": 100,
                "max": 1000
              },
              {
                "name": "section02",
                "description": "ActiveLayer",
                "icon": "img.png",
                "min": 500,
                "max": 1000
              },
              {
                "name": "section03",
                "description": "ActiveLayer",
                "icon": "img.png",
                "min": 100,
                "max": 600
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "product 02",
            "description": "sample product ONE",
            "icon": "product01.png",
            "section": [
              {
                "name": "section001",
                "description": "ActiveLayer",
                "icon": "img.png",
                "min": 100,
                "max": 1000
              },
              {
                "name": "section002",
                "description": "ActiveLayer",
                "icon": "img.png",
                "min": 500,
                "max": 1000
              },
              {
                "name": "section003",
                "description": "ActiveLayer",
                "icon": "img.png",
                "min": 100,
                "max": 600
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want push Id, typography and active as boolean to the array of objects and I want convert the JSON to Flat JSON as well (I want sections - typography to be same and Menu head, products typography to be different, similarly sections should have active as false and others as true)

I want output like this

```
[
   {
     "name":"MenuHead 01",
     "description":"sample Head 01",
     "icon":"sample01.png",
      "id":1,
      "typography":0,
      "active":true,
   },
   {
      "name":"product 01",
      "description":"sample product ONE",
      "icon":"product01.png",
      "id":2,
      "typography":1,
      "active":true,
   },
   {
       "name":"section01",
       "description":"ActiveLayer",
       "icon":"img.png",
       "min":100,
       "max":1000,
       "id":4,
       "typography":2,
       "active":false,
   },
   {
      "name":"section03",
       "description":"ActiveLayer",
       "icon":"img.png",
       "min":100,
       "max":600,
       "id":5,
       "typography":2,
       "active":false,
   },
   {
      "name":"section03",
      "description":"ActiveLayer",
      "icon":"img.png",
       "min":100,
       "max":600,
        "id":6,
       "typography":2,
       "active":false,
   }
]
```

I have tried this I am getting error and I want don't want to mention key example (obj.menuHead, obj.products, obj.sections)since the name will be changed later something like recursive way

```js
const tree = [
   {
      "menuHead":[
         {
            "name":"MenuHead 01",
            "description":"sample Head 01",
            "icon":"sample01.png",
            "products":[
               {
                  "name":"product 01",
                  "description":"sample product ONE",
                  "icon":"product01.png",
                  "sections":[
                     {
                        "name":"section01",
                        "description":"ActiveLayer",
                        "icon":"img.png",
                        "min":100,
                        "max":1000,
                     },
                     {
                        "name":"section02",
                        "description":"ActiveLayer",
                        "icon":"img.png",
                        "min":500,
                        "max":1000,

                     },
                     {
                        "name":"section03",
                        "description":"ActiveLayer",
                        "icon":"img.png",
                        "min":100,
                        "max":600,
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]


 function addUniqueID(arr: any[], i: number) {
    arr.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.typography = i;
      obj.id = i + 1;
      obj.active = true;
      if (obj.menuHead) {
        addUniqueID(obj.menuHead, i + 1);
      }
      else if (obj.sections) {
        addUniqueID(obj.sections, i + 1);
      }
      else if (obj.products) {
        addUniqueID(obj.products, i + 1);
      } else {
        obj.active = false;
      }
    });
  }

  addUniqueID(tree, 0);

  console.log(tree)

  const c = (item: any) => "name" in item ? [{
    name: item.name,
    id: item.id,
    typography: item.typography,
    active: item.active,
    description:item.description,
    icon: item.icon,
    min:item.min,
    max:item.max
  }] : []

  function flat(item: any) {

    if ("products" in item) {
      return c(item).concat(item.products.flatMap(flat))
    }

    if ("sections" in item) {
      return c(item).concat(item.sections.flatMap(flat))
    }

    return (
      c(item)
    )
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify (tree.flatMap(flat)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DYNAMIC KEYS**

You can try to use recursion for all data key loopings which is helpful in dynamic keys.

```js
const data = [{
  "menuHead": [{
    "name": "MenuHead 01",
    "description": "sample Head 01",
    "icon": "sample01.png",
    "products": [{
      "name": "product 01",
      "description": "sample product ONE",
      "icon": "product01.png",
      "section": [{
          "name": "section01",
          "description": "ActiveLayer",
          "icon": "img.png",
          "min": 100,
          "max": 1000,
        },
        {
          "name": "section02",
          "description": "ActiveLayer",
          "icon": "img.png",
          "min": 500,
          "max": 1000,

        },
        {
          "name": "section03",
          "description": "ActiveLayer",
          "icon": "img.png",
          "min": 100,
          "max": 600,
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]

function populateMenuItems(currentSet, typographyValue = -1, result = []) {
  for (const item of currentSet) {
    const itemKeys = Object.keys(item)
    const newItem = {
      typography: typographyValue,
      active: typographyValue < 2,
    }
    for (const itemKey of itemKeys) {
      if (Array.isArray(item[itemKey])) {
        populateMenuItems(item[itemKey], typographyValue + 1, result)
      } else {
        newItem[itemKey] = item[itemKey]
      }
    }
    if (typographyValue >= 0) {
      result.push(newItem)
    }
  }
  return result.sort((a, b) => a.typography - b.typography).map((item, index) => ({ ...item, id: index + 1 }))
}

const finalResult = populateMenuItems(data)

console.log(finalResult)
```

---

**STATIC KEYS**

You also can try this approach with `reduce` and looping through `products` and `section` for the new array population.

*Note that I'm using `currentId` for tracking id changes. You can get the final result with `finalResult.items`.*

```js
const data = [{
  "menuHead": [{
    "name": "MenuHead 01",
    "description": "sample Head 01",
    "icon": "sample01.png",
    "products": [{
      "name": "product 01",
      "description": "sample product ONE",
      "icon": "product01.png",
      "section": [{
          "name": "section01",
          "description": "ActiveLayer",
          "icon": "img.png",
          "min": 100,
          "max": 1000,
        },
        {
          "name": "section02",
          "description": "ActiveLayer",
          "icon": "img.png",
          "min": 500,
          "max": 1000,

        },
        {
          "name": "section03",
          "description": "ActiveLayer",
          "icon": "img.png",
          "min": 100,
          "max": 600,
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}]

const finalResult = data.reduce((result, current) => {
  if (!current.menuHead) {
    return result
  }

  for (const menuHeadItem of current.menuHead) {
    const {
      products,
      ...others
    } = menuHeadItem
    result.items.push({
      ...others,
      typography: 0,
      active: true,
      id: result.currentId
    })
    result.currentId++

    if (!products) {
      continue
    }

    for (const product of products) {
      const {
        section,
        ...others
      } = product
      result.items.push({
        ...others,
        typography: 1,
        active: true,
        id: result.currentId
      })
      result.currentId++

      for (const sectionItem of section) {
        result.items.push({
          ...sectionItem,
          typography: 2,
          active: false,
          id: result.currentId
        })
        result.currentId++
      }
    }
  }

  return result
}, {
  currentId: 1,
  items: []
})

console.log(finalResult.items)
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, Is there any chance can we not use keys like products, section, menuHead since the key can be changed in the future.

Comment: there are always arrays? if that is the case, I can modify my answer accordingly @tinyVariant

Comment: I updated my answer, you can verify it again @tinyVariant

Comment: Hi @Nick,  Thanks for the answer, I am getting this error for result.push =>  Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
    61 |       }
    62 |       if (typographyValue >= 0) {
  > 63 |         result.push(newItem)
       |                     ^^^^^^^
    64 |       }
    65 |     }

Comment: You can add types to the function params like `populateMenuItems(currentSet: any[], typographyValue: number = -1, result: any[] = [])` @tinyVariant

Comment: Hi @Nick, I have like two different MenuHead01, MenuHead02 and two different sections but tree structure is not aligned properly, I have edited the JSON data above, Thanks